# How to use $_post data from another page in a function

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on a php project, which is in wordpress, I use to send data from one page and use this data in another page, I am using $_POST to get data from that page. But When I try to get the data in function or in if block it becomes empty, but When I use it out side of function or if block, it works, (works means I get output as I want from that page in echo). How do I make that work in function or if block,

**First file** from which I send data

```
<form action="http://localhost/w/download.php" target="_blank" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cate" value="'.$categories[0]->name.'" /><br />
<input type="hidden" name="url" value="'.get_permalink().'" /><br />
<div align="center">
<input type="image" alt="Download" height="99" src="https://www.google.co.in/logos/doodles/2016/fathers-day-2016-us-5562299671642112-hp.jpg" width="184" />
</div>
</form>
```

**Second file** which I used to get data and make it useful for me.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["downloadfile"])) {
$urls=$_POST['url'];
echo $urls;// Does not show the out put and
//doing something 
}
?>
<form method="POST">
  <input type="submit" value="DOWNLOAD FILE" name="downloadfile"/>
</form>
```

But when I try to echo $_POST data outside of if block I got that value which I want Like:

**Second file**

```
<?php
$urls=$_POST['url'];
echo $urls; // shows me the link
if(isset($_POST["downloadfile"])) {
//doing something 
}
?>
<form method="POST">
  <input type="submit" value="DOWNLOAD FILE" name="downloadfile"/>
</form>
```

It shows me that variable $urls is empty. But when I use it out side of if block and echo it shows me output, that what I want.
Can anyone tell me How do I use this in a function or if block in second file, or I am doing some wrong way, So please tell me the right way.

***The most important thing is that If any one want to give this question a down vote, please do that But Please Please Comment below Why Did you do that, I am not a genius php developer like you, I just learn from my mistake***

Comment: is the first form originaly wrapped in an `echo '<form.....</form>';`?? if not, `$categories` and `get_permalink()` won't do anything.

Comment: This happens because you don't pass `$_POST["downloadfile"]` and your `if` fails.

Comment: If you are submitting the form from file One to the Second file, your first form doesn't have `$_POST['downloadfile']` which is why it never executes the statements in the `if($_POST['downloadfile'])` check.

Comment: @Jeff Yes it is wrapped in echo

Comment: @u_mulder I have passed it on my second file, but due to $urls is empty it does not work at all.

Comment: @AndrewNolan Even If I use $_POST['downloadfile'] in first form. it gives me an empty $_POST['url']. I have to get that data to run the next line. Can you please help me

Answer (score 0):

Use `if(isset($_POST["url"])) {` instead of `if(isset($_POST["downloadfile"])) {`

Comment: If I use if(isset($_POST["url"])) { instead of if(isset($_POST["downloadfile"])) I get an error that $_POST['url'] is empty

Comment: @AdityaPandey Then you are sending your data from "secondFile" instead of "firstFile" if your paste here is 100% correct ;)

Comment: @Xatenev No actually this answer suggested me to do the above thing. I only give him a response what will happen If I do that thing.

Comment: @AdityaPandey Yea exactly, and I tell you if that happens what you described above, you are sending your data from "secondFile" instead of "firstFile" which is wrong.

Comment: @Xatenev I use a form in firstFile to send data and there is an another form in secondFile to start its work after getting data ($_POST['url']) from firstFile

Comment: you dont send the data from firstFile. You dont have to explain me what you are TRYING to do. I know what your trying to do and I tell you what is wrong :/

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the submit be in the first form?

Just put this line:

```
<input type="submit" value="DOWNLOAD FILE" name="downloadfile"/>
```

Right below

```
 <input type="image" alt="Download" height="99" src="https://www.google.co.in/logos/doodles/2016/fathers-day-2016-us-5562299671642112-hp.jpg" width="184" />
```

One file should send all the data, and the other file should get (POST) the data. Put

```
 <?php
 if(isset($_POST["downloadfile"])) {
 $urls=$_POST['url'];
 //doing something 
 }
 ?>
```

At the top of the second file

---

---

#### EDIT

Okay, I did a bit of testing.. I think you're missing the php tags.

**First file**

```
<form action="http://localhost/w/download.php" target="_blank" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cate" value="' <?php $categories[0]->name ?>'" /><br />
<input type="hidden" name="url" value="'<?php get_permalink() ?>'" /><br />
<div align="center">
    <input type="image" alt="Download" height="99" src="https://www.google.co.in/logos/doodles/2016/fathers-day-2016-us-5562299671642112-hp.jpg" width="184" />
    <input type="submit" value="DOWNLOAD FILE" name="downloadfile"/>
</div>
```

**download.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["downloadfile"])) {
    $urls=$_POST['url'];
}
echo $urls;
?>
```

When I run this on my own server, I get errors, but I think that is because I don't have get_permalink() defined.

## Edit 2

Here is the first file

```
<form action="http://localhost/w/download.php" target="_blank" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cate" value="<?php $categories[0]->name ?>" /><br />
<input type="hidden" name="url" value="<?php get_permalink() ?>" /><br />
<div align="center">
        <input type="image" value="submit" name="downloadfile" alt="Download" height="99" width="184" src="https://www.google.co.in/logos/doodles/2016/fathers-day-2016-us-5562299671642112-hp.jpg" />
</div>
```

And here is the second

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['downloadfile_x'])) { //Name of the image, and x coordinate
   $urls=$_POST['url'];
}
echo $urls;
?>
```

Comment: I have put your first line, but It start doing it works and showing an error that $_POST['url'] is empty

Comment: This line is should be in second file  <input type="submit" value="DOWNLOAD FILE" name="downloadfile"/> And I have to echo or use data from $_POST in if block NOT OUTSIDE

Comment: Okay. If you want the submit in the second file, how are you going to submit the first form?

Comment: clicking on google image, it will redirect me to download.php file than There is another form, from which, When I click it should start the work, But My problem is How do I get that url

Comment: @AdityaPandey Look at my second edit. This uses the image as a submit button, and sends the value to the download page

Comment: Yes it working but outside of if block, I have to use that data in my if block not the outside